# dynamic_cast in constant evaluation

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, constexpr, dynamic-cast

In following program the constructor of polymorphic `struct A` tries to `dynamic_cast` `this` to a pointer of a inherited `struct B`. It is done twice: using normal and constant evaluations, and the result of both is printed.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    constexpr A();
    virtual void f() {}
    bool x;
};

struct B : A {};

constexpr A::A() { 
    x = dynamic_cast<B*>(this);
}
constexpr bool b = B{}.x;

int main() {
    std::cout << B{}.x << b;
}
```

With normal evaluation `std::cout << B{}.x` everything is simple and `0` is printed, since in the constructor of `A` the object cannot be cast to a child class.

But with constant evaluation the compilers diverge. Only Clang prints second `0`. MSVC already prints second `1` meaning that the result of `dynamic_cast` was not `nullptr`. And GCC prints vague error:

```
<source>:14:24:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'B()'
<source>:9:8:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '((B*)this)->B::<anonymous>.A::A()'
<source>:14:24: error: '((&<anonymous>.B::<anonymous>) != 0)' is not a constant expression
   14 | constexpr bool b = B{}.x;
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xr8rdP93a

Is the program above well defined and if yes, what shall it print?

P.S. I think it is not a duplicate of two other questions:

- [dynamic_cast of "this" inside constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299266/dynamic-cast-of-this-inside-constructor)
- [dynamic_cast "this" to derived type: when is it legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946327/dynamic-cast-this-to-derived-type-when-is-it-legal)

because the main focus here is constant evaluation, which is not covered there at all.